# Android date with added milliseconds not at the correct time

Tags: java, android, date

What I am trying to do is store a date, represented by a long of milliseconds, that is the next midnight from the current time. So, posting this at 10:11 PM, I would want a date representing 12:00 AM tomorrow morning. For this task, I wrote this line of code (knowing that there are 86400000 milliseconds in one day):

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + (86400000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() % 86400000));
```

The line is designed to calculate the extra milliseconds from the last midnight, substract that from one whole day to find the time until the next midnight, then add that to the current time so that the new value is the value of the next midnight. For whatever reason though, the date object I am using to debug spits out "Wed Apr 20 20:00:00 EDT 2016" when calling the #toString() method. The current time is said to be "Tue Apr 19 22:08:34 EDT 2016" at the same time as the other date is being calculated.

This means that the long of milliseconds is actually representing 8:00 PM the next day, while I want it to represent 12:00 AM. Can anyone help me spot the flaw in my logic?

I most likely am missing something obvious, so bear with me.

NOTE: I also tried calculating the time like this:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - (System.currentTimeMillis() % 86400000) + 86400000;
```

But this resulted in the same Date object.

Comment: You need to adjust for your timezone, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is in UTC

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to adjust for your timezone. Here is a simple way to achieve this.

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + (86400000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() % 86400000));
time -= tz.getOffset(time);

System.out.println(new Date(time));
```

Comment: This sets the time to represent midnight two days from the current date. When I print out the date object, it returns midnight on 4/21 (the date is 4/19 here). I can just subtract one day in this case, but will it always be one day ahead? Just asking for safety purposes.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using flawed troublesome date-time classes that have long been supplanted, first by the Joda-Time library and now it's successor, the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of java.time has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 and then adapted to Android by the ThreeTenABP project.

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC, with a resolution in nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Time zone is crucial to determining a date. It may already be “tomorrow” to the east of you or “yesterday” to the west.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( zoneId );
```

To get the first moment of the day, do not assume that time is `00:00:00.0`.  Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time may result in a different time. Let java.time determine that time-of-day. To do that we must go through the `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate today = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

Days are not always 24 hours long, which is an incorrect assumption in you question and code. Again, let java.time determine the following day with a call to `plusDays`.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.plusDays( 1 );
ZonedDateTime zdtTomorrowStart = tomorrow.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

I suggest you avoid tracking date-time values as a count from epoch. That is prone to error, and is terribly difficult to debug. And you will be losing data as you go from nanosecond resolution to milliseconds. But if you insist.

```
long millis = zdtTomorrowStart.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct time calculation can be tricky, there are quite a few corner cases. I think the simplest solution to avoid it is :

```
    // now, with current timezone and locale
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    // tomorrow
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    // midnight
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    // get the resulting date
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
```